# How to customize a vector in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable, android-5.0-lollipop

I am working with an Android app (using API 21) in which I can change the color of a vector manually depends on previous Activity, but I have a problem, I can not access the 'Path' object in my xml file

```html
<!-- drawable/chevron_left.xml -->
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="left"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">
    <path
        android:id="@+id/chervon_left"
        android:fillColor="#000"
        android:pathData="M15.41,16.58L10.83,12L15.41,7.41L14,6L8,12L14,18L15.41,16.58Z" />
</vector>
```

So how can I customize this vector in MainActivity.java file ?
I read this but it did not work: [Working with Drawables](https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html)

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the VectorDrawable at run-time? It's not clear from the title of the post.

Comment: I am so sorry for this and yes, I want to change the value of "path" variable in this xml file, can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

basically, use @color.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="left"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">
<path
        android:id="@+id/chervon_left"
        android:fillColor="@color/purple_200"
        android:pathData="M15.41,16.58L10.83,12L15.41,7.41L14,6L8,12L14,18L15.41,16.58Z" />
```